# Upload to Artifactory using Java client

Tags: java, artifactory

I use Artifactory Java client, and cant upload file to Artifactory. My code is very simple, taken from Artifactory Java Client test folder:

```
artifactoryClient = ArtifactoryClient.create("localhost:8081", "admin", "admin");
InputStream content = new ByteArrayInputStream("I want to test my upload!".getBytes());
UploadableArtifact apAtrifact =  artifactoryClient.repository("ext-snapshotlocal").upload("test/content.txt", content);
File res = apAtrifact.doUpload();
```

I got error:

```
02:44:26.014 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - >> Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
02:44:26.014 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - >> "I want to test my upload!"
02:44:26.248 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - << "HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden[\r][\n]"
02:44:26.250 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - << "Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1[\r][\n]"
02:44:26.250 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - << "Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8[\r][\n]"
02:44:26.250 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - << "Content-Length: 961[\r][\n]"
02:44:26.250 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - << "Date: Sun, 24 Nov 2013 00:44:25 GMT[\r][\n]"
02:44:26.250 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - << "[\r][\n]"
02:44:26.250 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.i.conn.DefaultClientConnection - Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
02:44:26.250 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - << HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
02:44:26.250 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - << Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
02:44:26.250 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - << Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
02:44:26.250 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - << Content-Length: 961
02:44:26.250 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - << Date: Sun, 24 Nov 2013 00:44:25 GMT
02:44:26.253 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient - Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
02:44:26.254 [main] DEBUG groovyx.net.http.RESTClient - Response code: 403; found handler: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.MethodClosure@41feeacb
02:44:26.254 [main] DEBUG groovyx.net.http.RESTClient - Parsing response as: application/json
02:44:26.265 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - << "<html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/7.0.39 - Error report</title><style><!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}--></style> </head><body><h1>HTTP Status 403 - </h1><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><p><b>type</b> Status report</p><p><b>message</b> <u></u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>Access to the specified resource has been forbidden.</u></p><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><h3>Apache Tomcat/7.0.39</h3></body></html>"
02:44:26.272 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.i.c.BasicClientConnectionManager - Releasing connection org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl@4349f1b6
02:44:26.272 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.i.c.BasicClientConnectionManager - Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
02:44:26.278 [main] WARN  groovyx.net.http.RESTClient - Error parsing 'text/html;charset=utf-8' response
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream@494f0b41; line: 1, column: 2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1284) ~[services-0.9-all.jar:na]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:588) ~[services-0.9-all.jar:na]
```

Could you help me with this issue?

Comment: provide curl command as well to let others know for the correct input/output like `$ curl -v -u admin:admin -X PUT http://localhost:8080/ext-snapshotlocal/test/content.txt --data testfile.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually had this exact thing happen to me. I assume you're using [this client](https://github.com/JFrogDev/artifactory-client-java). It turned out I wasn't being specific enough in the URL. I needed to provide the full path, like so:

```
artifactoryClient = ArtifactoryClient.create("http://localhost:8081/artifactory", "admin", "password");
```

I'd assume that if you're using a separate container to run it other than what bin/artifactory.sh uses, you might have to tweak that URL.

Answer (score 0):

You got `403 Forbidden`, so you probably should check your credentials. In case of default Artifactory installation, they should be `admin:password`, not `admin:admin`.

Another very possible cause is the [encrypted password policy](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/plugins/servlet/mobile#content/view/25067965). If the policy is set to "mandatory", you have to use encrypted password when creating the client.

BTW, you try to upload a non-snapshot file to a snapshot repository. You should check whether it accepts releases, otherwise you'll get `409` after getting the credentials straight.

Comment: I put admin/admin for example. credentials are different. I tried to upload to all reposotories and error the same

Comment: Yes, you are right about credentials, but its weird - from java client can't access with my credentials (even created new admin user, and still doesn't work)